# PHPMailer: Dynamic gmail forwarding

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer, gmail-api

I do not know if what I want to do is possible (but finding out that it isn't would be useful in itself).

I cannot use my company's gmail account "real.business@gmail.com" directly with PHPMailer. I can, however, use an intermediary gmail account "fake.12345.account@gmail.com" which can have "less secure apps" enabled, which permits SMTP verification.

However I do not want to have the emails be sent from this fake.12345.account@gmail.com account (wouldn't look particularly professional) - but rather the company's gmail account.

I can send the emails from the intermediary account to real.business@gmail.com; either through the editing of the PHPMailer parameters, or by automatically forwarding emails from fake.12345.account@gmail.com to the company account.

The problem lies in how real.business@gmail.com can then successfully email the email (or  at least appear to be the sender), as originally intended.

The code so far

```
$Mail = new PHPMailer();
$Mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
$Mail->Host        = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Sets SMTP server for gmail
$Mail->SMTPDebug   = 0; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
$Mail->SMTPAuth    = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
$Mail->SMTPSecure  = "tls"; //Secure conection
$Mail->Port        = 587; // set the SMTP port to gmail's port
$Mail->Username    = 'fake.12345.account@gmail.com'; // gmail account username
$Mail->Password    = 'a_password'; // gmail account password
$Mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 =   low)
$Mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
$Mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
$Mail->Subject     = 'Mail test';
$Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$Mail->From        = 'testing.num.101@gmail.com'; //Your email adress (Gmail overwrites it anyway)
$Mail->FromName    = 'Testing Again';
$Mail->WordWrap    = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line

$Mail->addAddress($personEmail); // To: the PERSON WE WANT TO EMAIL
$Mail->isHTML( TRUE );
$Mail->Body    = ' Good news '.$personName.'! The email sent correctly!';
$Mail->AltBody = 'This is a test mail';
$Mail->Send();
$Mail->SmtpClose();

if(!$Mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $Mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
```

So the issue is: not having the email sent to $personEmail from fake.12345.account@gmail.com (that's trivial) but rather how to send the email from fake.12345.account@gmail.com to real.business@gmail.com such that real.business@gmail.com forwards the message to $personEmail

Comment: I'm not following. You're saying it's trivial to send emails `TO:` $personEmail, `FROM:`real.business@gmail.com via fake.12345.account@gmail.com? But this is not possible either (The comments in your code agree! `(Gmail overwrites it anyway)`)

Comment: @HPierce oh no: it's trivial to send emails TO: $personEmail, FROM:fake.12345.account@gmail.com. It's the **via** bit that's the problem!

Comment: Regardless of the problem itself (which I don't think you can fix in gmail), you've based your code on an old example and are thus probably using an old version of PHPMailer, which never helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is really relaying, which is usually configured in the mail server config (not the messages), but you don't have access to anything like that in gmail.

You can set allowed aliases in gmail, but I would guess that these are not allowed to overlap with existing gmail account names as that would be a major security hole. Why not enable "less secure apps" on the main account? It's not as if it is actually any less secure - if anything it's better, because the setup to use OAuth2 is so deeply complex and unpleasant...

That said, rather than trying to do all this forgery, you may be interested in [this PR](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/pull/421) and [associated docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2). It's fairly likely the xoauth branch will get merged into master and released without any further changes as PHPMailer 5.2.11, and it would very helpful if you could give it a try.

Comment: Hmmm. I suspected as much. The business account is based on gmail, albeit with a different domain name, and many features are disabled (one of which is allowing less secure apps). I'm baulking at broaching oauth2 use with PHPMailer (getting anything email related to work tends to be tricky at the best of times!). In particular, those associated docs - while very nicely written, mention a "get_auth_token.php" which seems to be absent from PHPMailer :/

Comment: Thanks - I wrote them! You'll find get_auth_token.php in the [xoauth branch](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/xoauth), it's not in master yet.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer is made for sending.

What you want to do is forward an email. This implies receiving the email and then sending it through.

What you need is some kind of **IMAP** client in php, that will allow you to **read** the emails on fake.12345.account@gmail.com (and maybe real.business@gmail.com). Then **save their body and title** and pass it to PHPMailer. You can then use **PHPMailer** to **send** the emails with real.business@gmail.com.

Comment: He knows that - the problem is that he's trying to send while faking another account.

Comment: if `$Mail->Username` and `$Mail->From` are different the mails will get filtered as spam. Also how are you going to send an existing email with PHPMailer (which is what forwarding implies) without opening the email first...

Comment: Username and From do not have to match in gmail if it's on your list of allowed aliases. In any other system, the username does not necessarily appear anywhere in the message and will have no effect on spam filtering - you may be confusing it with the Sender address, which is quite separate. What he's actually describing is a mail relay, not forwarding, which requires direct control of the mail server, which isn't available on gmail, so this is something of a lost cause.